# Form inputs empty on second submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

**Project setup:**

- PostgreSQL database
- NodeJS + AngularJS + Semantic UI application

I'm trying to add some data to the view by filling in a form contained within a popup.

I'm initialising this popup using an `ng-click` event on a button like so:

```
<button id="add-popup" class="primary ui button" ng-click="addPopup()">
  <i class="plus icon"></i>
</button>
```

The popup is then opened on the page using the following code block:

```
$scope.addPopup = function() {
  $('#add-popup').popup({
      on: 'click',
      position: 'bottom center',
      html: '<form id="addForm" class="ui form">\
               <div class="field">\
                 <label>Field 1</label>\
                 <input id="field_1" type="text">\
               </div>\
               ...
               <button onclick="$(\'#add-object\').click();" class="ui fluid positive button">Add</button>\
             </form>'
  }).popup('show');
}
```

No problems there. Everything works fine.

I fill in the form inputs, press the submit button, and an Angular function called `addObject` gets called by simulating a click on a hidden button on the page (with id `add-object`, as seen in the above code).

The `addObject` function looks like this:

```
$scope.addObject = function() {
  var newObject = {
      "field_1": $('#field_1', '#addForm').val(),
      ...
    };

    console.log(newObject);

    // The database interaction logic is omitted for brevity,
    // it's tested and that piece of the code works
};
```

First time I fill in the form, this is the output of the `console.log`:

```
{
  "field_1": "entered text",
  ...
}
```

I press submit, form submits everything, the new object gets added to the scope. Everything works as expected.

Second time I try to do this, I'm getting the following `console.log` output:

```
{
  "field_1": "",
  ...
}
```

No matter what I enter or do, the value for **all** of my fields remains an empty string.

I've already tried doing a `$scope.$apply` in various different places, checking where along the whole process this happens, but it's effectively happening after getting the values from the form.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to

1. **Why** this is happening
2. **What I can do** about this?

---

Disclaimer: I know this code needs a lot of cleanup. It's a project where the deadline is too tight to refactor, and a chunk of the ugly code damage had already been done before I even started working on this project, so it's not my decision to work like this, sadly enough.

Comment: I will suggest to create directive for popup and pass the values

Comment: We switched to Semantic UI Angular to solve this problem. We're guessing it has something to do with everything being contained in modals, but it's pretty vague where the exact problem is. So the problem's solved, but not with an actual solution to this question, rather a different approach.